# Are there any better Java CLI debugger tools better than jdb?

Tags: java, android, debugging, command-line, jdb

I have successfully debugged an Android app with *jdb* today. But I found *jdb* is not as handy as *gdb* for me: the convenience and functionality which *jdb* provides are grossly inferior to those provided by *gdb*.

Are there any better Java debuggers **that can be used in command-line mode** to choose from?  Preferably this would be as powerful, convenient, and functional as *gdb* is for regular programs, but for Java.

Again, I am **not interested** in anything that is part of some IDE.  This needs to be a command-line tool like *gdb* is.  I use *vim* for editing my code, not an IDE.

Comment: Any reason for not using an IDE like Eclipse with an integrated debugger?

Comment: I am debugging on android devices. And eclipse works not very well. Sometimes can enter debug mode, but sometimes without luck. But jdb can always debug normally. And i haven't open eclipse for a long time since i start developing with vim.

Comment: Eclipse is definitly the way to go on android. The debugger works fine but some devices have some troubles on implementing debugging features of the android platform and maintaining the connection with the debbuger. Try eclipse + ADT, the debugger is just working as expected, maybe try to put your hands on a more robust device for developments.

Comment: In fact, the common app can debug but not the special apps. Such the stock contacts. calendar...

Answer (score 0):

[rlwrap-jdb](https://github.com/pimlott/rlwrap-jdb), as mentioned in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194360/3780389) is just a wrapper around jdb but brings it much closer to a gdb experience. From the rlwrap-jdb README.md:

> rlwrap-jdb is a rearguard effort to make jdb almost usable. It uses to rlwrap not to add not only command-line editing and history, but (using rlwrap's nifty filter mechanism) handy aliases, command repetition, and completion of breakpoints and variables.

To use, just prepend `rlwrap-jdb` to your jdb command: `rlwrap-jdb jdb ...`.

Comment: `rlwrap-jdb` seems to depend on `rlwrap` which appears to be defunct, or at least the link in the github readme is dead: https://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/ EDIT: ok, turns out I can `brew install rlwrap`